# Index Match with Multiple Criteria while looking for a certain string

Tags: excel, indexing, match

```
   A          B          C
1  Name       Last Name  ID
2  Ben        Dafflin    ID1001
3  Yu         Yiin       ID1002
5  Max        Gray       ID1003
6  John Carl  Flit       ID1004
```

```
Situation 1 : Index Match with wildcards "*" (Working Fine!)
Formula    : =INDEX($C:$C,MATCH("*John*",$A:$A,0))
Result      : ID1004


Situation 2 : Index Match with multiple criteria (Working Fine!)
Formula     : =IFERROR(INDEX(D:D,MATCH(1,(B:B="Flit")*(C:C="John Carl"),0)),"")
Result      : ID1004
```

Problem:
In situation 2, if it only looks for cells with `"Carl"` or `"*Carl*"` it doesn't work. Any suggestion how will I use the situation 2 having an index match with multiple criteria but can still look for cells that contains such specific string.

Comment: Do you have Office 365?

Answer (score 1):

To have your 2nd formula return a value, you just need to reference the correct columns:  `=IFERROR(INDEX(C:C,MATCH(1,(B:B="Flit")*(A:A="John Carl"),0)),"")`

If you want to use wild cards with `MATCH` where you have multiple criteria, you can try:

```
=INDEX(C:C,MATCH(1,1/(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("*Carl*",A:A))*(B:B="Flit")),0))
```

If you have Office 365

```
=FILTER(C:C,ISNUMBER(SEARCH("*Carl*",A:A))*(B:B="Flit"))
```

Comment: The first case (non-365) returns `#N/A` if either `Carl` isn't in `A:A` or `Flit` isn't in `B:B`. Of course, that also happens if the OP 1st formula fails (even after you fixed it). So perhaps that's ok (hard to tell).

Comment: @Spinner I thought he wanted to match both, so I would expect that result.

Comment: As I said, hard to tell. Their 2nd formula (the one they wanted to adapt further) returns "" if not found (whereas their 1st doesn't). Either way, I'm sure they can adapt it, if that's what they want.

Answer (score 0):

**Lookup when Matching to Multiple Columns**
There's another way to approach this, which is simpler and may well be a better fit:

```
{=INDEX(C:C,MATCH("*CarlFlit",A:A&B:B,0))}
```

The above is of course an array formula (hence the opening `{` and closing `}`)
a) The array matched is the rows of columns `A` and `B` concatenated into single strings
b) This specific example is of course looking for (`*`wild-carded) `*CarlFlit`
c) Which of course, could be any combination of values and valid `MATCH` `wildcards`

If the values being looked for are in cells (rather than hardcoded into the formula) simply refer to those cells:

```
{=INDEX(C:C,MATCH(E2&F2,A:A&B:B,0))}
```

To add checking for no-match (using first example above):

```
{=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH("*CarlFlit",A:A&B:B,0)),INDEX(C:C,MATCH("*CarlFlit",A:A&B:B,0)),"Not Found")}
```

**Additional information**
The formula  above  can be **expanded** to accommodate matching across any number of columns. 
o Simply `&` in each additional column (in whatever order suites your purpose).

For **performance** reasons, it's not a good idea to have lookup functions looking at entire columns.
a) Better to use (e.g.) `{=INDEX($C$1:$C$1000,MATCH("*CarlFlit",$A$1:$A$1000&$B$1:$B$1000,0))}`.
b) Where `1000` is of course an example `last row` in your lookup range.